# Difference between createCriteria and createAlias

Tags: java, hibernate

I was reading hibernate criteria document here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

I had used it many time and I am normally use **createAlias()** to join table, here they have provide two methods to make a join and fetch data from the tables, there are:

```
 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createCriteria("kittens")
         .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Iz%") )
     .list();

 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createAlias("kittens", "kit")
     .add( Restrictions.like("kit.name", "Iz%") )
     .list();
```

So I am not able to distinguish difference between `.createCriteria("kittens")` and `createAlias("kittens", "kit")` or may be I am not getting what this code exactly do, can someone help me to clear my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

> The only difference is that `CreateCriteria` has 2 additional
>   overloads without the alias parameter, this difference is long gone in
>   the latest versions.
>
> But essentially the application is slightly
>   different in its usage is that **`CreateCriteria` uses its relations of
>   mapping from parent to child, whilst with `CreateAlias` you defined them
>   with your customized alias names from the root**.

Read more from [here](http://mashupweb.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/difference-between-createcriteria-and-createalias/).

Answer (score 2):

Main Difference is that `Criterias' createCriteria()` creates and returns Sub Criteria (new Criteria Object).This is useful if you want to create criteria for subquery.
**Here is what documentation says about its return type**

> Returns:
>   the created "sub criteria"

`Criteria's CreateAlias()` returns existing Criteria Object
**Here is what documentation says about its return type**

> Returns:
>    this (for method chaining)

Comment: Read document carefully it will not create subquery it will make join only with default type 'Inner Join'. So this is not a difference at all.

Comment: Read the return type documentation carefully.i have updated my answer to include that portion

Comment: I was talking about subquery, read this line in the document 'Functionally equivalent to createCriteria(String, int) using CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN for the joinType.', so can you give example how subquery can be fire using this? as far as I know we need to use detached criteria for that.