# what is the difference between return this vs return new Class()

Tags: hibernate, oop

recently i was going through an article in hibernate.I have seen this please enlighten me on this

```
public Criteria createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType) {
    return new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, alias, joinType );//return new object
}


public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType) {
    new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, alias, joinType );
    return this;//return this
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: i have got little bit of answer but not understood properly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062286/difference-between-creatcriteria-and-createalias

Answer (score 1):

First example will return a new instance of the type `Subcriteria`. Second one will return current instance. See about this keyword in java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java).

So the difference is simple.

1. New
2. Existing (current)

The link you provided in the comment clearly answers the question. Have a look again.

Comment: Thanks for link @nabin